# convert ereg to preg - example given

Tags: php, regex

I am getting a `Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated` in an old plugin I am updating.  I need to update the following two:

```
ereg( "([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,4})", $fecha, $mifecha);

ereg( "([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,4})", $fecha, $mifecha);
```

Can someone help me understand what to change to convert them to preg?